# Java IO: Using scanner and printWriter to copy the contents of a text file and put them in another text file

Tags: java, file, io, java.util.scanner, printwriter

Alright so I have a very small program I'm working on designed to take the contents of a text file, test.txt, and put them in another empty file testCopied.txt . The trick is that I want to use Scanner and printWriter as I am trying to understand these a bit better.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CopyA
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      String Input_filename = args[0];
      String Output_filename = args[1];
      char r = args[2].charAt(0);

      try
      {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(Input_filename));
         FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(Output_filename);
         PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(fw);

         while(sc.hasNextLine())
         {
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            printer.write(s);
         }
         sc.close();               
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {
         System.out.println(ioe);
      }
   }
}
```

This compiles, but when I look at testCopied.txt it is still blank, and hasn't had test.txt's content transferred to it. What am I doing wrong? Java IO is pretty confusing to me, so I'm trying to get a better grasp on it. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: close your `PrintWriter` when you're done with it, preferably in a `finally` block. This causes the writer to flush its contents, writing it all to file. You should also terminate each line or the new file will have everything on one line.

Comment: @Zircon How do you terminate each line? Is it some form of while loop used here or is there another Java IO specific thing I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed out `flush`() and `close`() for the `PrintWriter` object which you need to add

and then use the line separator using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` while writing each line into second file.

You can refer the below code:

```
PrintWriter printer = null;
Scanner sc = null;
try
  {
     String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

     sc = new Scanner(new File(Input_filename));
     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(Output_filename);
     printer = new PrintWriter(fw);

     while(sc.hasNextLine())
     {
        String s = sc.nextLine()+lineSeparator; //Add line separator
        printer.write(s);
     }
  }
  catch(IOException ioe)
  {
     System.out.println(ioe);
  } finally {
    if(sc != null) {
       sc.close();  
    }
    if(printer != null) {
      printer.flush();
      printer.close();
     }
 }
```

Also, ensure that you are always closing resources in the `finally` block (which you have missed out for Scanner object in your code).

Comment: Thank you! That worked! However I have one question. The content in test.txt is spread out on 5 different lines. When it is copied to testCopied.txt, it is just one long line. Is there a way to edit the code so that the formatting stays constant between the two files?

Comment: you need to add lineSeparator, updated the code, you can refer above answer